# SPRING REST controller - return image AND json values

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

I have built a rest web service, using SPRING and Hibernate.
I have 2 entities : Image and user, linked with a oneToOne annotation.

When I try to return the user details AND the image corresponding to this user, I get this error : 
"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation"

When I do it separately It works fine, but when I do it in one route, I get this error.

### Here is my controller :

```
@CrossOrigin(
    origins = "*", 
    methods = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.DELETE}, 
    allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    ImageRepository imageRepsository;



    doesn't work-->  @RequestMapping(value="/{userId}/getUserAndImage",method=RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE )
    public Optional<User> getUserAndImage(@PathVariable Long userId) {

    return userRepository.findById(userId);
}

    works fine--> @RequestMapping(value="/{userId}/image", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public byte[] getUserImage(@PathVariable Long userId) {
    byte[] image = (imageRepsository.findImageWithUserId(userId)).getImage();

        return image;
}
```

### Here are entities :

User entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Size(max=100)
@Column
private String nom;

@NotNull
@Size(max=250)
@Column
private String prenom;


@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,
          cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Image image;

//getters and setters
}
```

Image entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="images")
public class Image {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name="image")
@Lob
private byte[] image;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private User user;

//getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the annotation, **produce** set as MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, then your code return response as User object. As result it throw that exception because spring expect your code to return JPEG type file only.

What can i suggest here,use  **produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE**, and convert your image from byte[] to base64 string then return response as json object

Comment: yes sorry, here is the complete log : org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation.